# Using a scanner input to define the number of scanner inputs required

Tags: java, loops, console

I have made it a little further. It turns out I can use loops but not arrays in my assignment. So here's the current version (keep in mind no final calculations or anything yet.) So if you look at the homework method, you can see I am asking for the "number of assignments." Now, for each assignment, I need to ask for and sum both the Earned Score and the Maximum Possible Score. So for instance, if there were 3 assignments, they might have earned scores of 18, 22, and 29, and maximum possible scores of 20, 25, and 30 respectively. I need to grab both using the console, but I don't know how to get two variables using the same loop (or in the same method).

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        welcomeScreen();
      weightCalculator();
      homework();

    }

    public static void welcomeScreen() {

        System.out.println("This program accepts your homework scores and");
        System.out.println("scores from two exams as input and computes");
        System.out.println("your grade in the course.");
      System.out.println();

    }


    public static void weightCalculator() {

      System.out.println("Homework and Exam 1 weights? ");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = console.nextInt();
            int b = console.nextInt();

            int c = 100 - a - b;

         System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Using weights of " + a + " " + b + " " + c);

    }

   public static void homework() {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Number of assignments? ");
        int totalAssignments = console.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalAssignments; i++) {
                System.out.print(" #" + i + "? ");
                int next = console.nextInt();
                sum += next;
            }       

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: show your efforts (code) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly your problem is, so I will try to give you some remarks. This is how I would start (of course there are other ways to implement this):

First of all - create Assignment class to hold all informations in nice, wrapped form:

```
public class Assignment {
    private int pointsEarned;
    private int pointsTotal;

    public Assignment(int pointsEarned, int pointsTotal) {
        this.pointsEarned = pointsEarned;
        this.pointsTotal = pointsTotal;
    }
    ...getters, setters...
}
```

To request number of assignments you can use simply nextInt() method and assign it to some variable:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfAssignments = sc.nextInt();
```

Then, use this variable to create some collection of assignments (for example using simple array):

```
Assignment[] assignments = new Assignment[numberOfAssignments];
```

Next, you can fill this collection using scanner again:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAssignments; i++) {
   int pointsEarned = sc.nextInt();
   int pointsTotal = sc.nextInt();
   assignments[i] = new Assignment(pointsEarned, pointsTotal)
}
```

So here, you have filled collection of assignments. You can now print it, calculate average etc.

I hope above code gives you some remarks how to implement this.

Comment: Wow, thanks baza92! I was coming at it all completely backwards. This direction will allow me to gather the inputs I need and then pass them into the calculations I need to perform.